# Pointers to Pointers - should old pointer still exist?

Tags: vhdl

In ActiveHDL, I get en error of a NULL pointer reference on the report line. I argue that ptr should still hold the old pointer value, and hence should not be NULL. I've raised this as a ticket and the response was that the behaviour is correct, and in VHDL 2018 it is still correct due to garbage collection.

I would argue that it is wrong in both standards as `ptr` still holds the pointer reference to the old data, so shouldn't have been made null and/or should not be garbage collected (in VHDL2018).

What can I try to resolve this?

### Edit

Here's the code from the defect:

```
entity int_append_test is
end entity;

architecture test of int_append_test is

  type int_vector_ptr_t is access integer_vector;
  type int_vector_ptr_ptr_t is access int_vector_ptr_t;

  procedure append( variable ptr  : inout int_vector_ptr_t;
                    constant val  : in    integer ) is
    variable p  : int_vector_ptr_t;
  begin
    p := ptr;

    if ptr = null then
      ptr := new integer_vector'( (0 => val) );
    else
      ptr := new integer_vector'(p.all & val);
    end if;

    DEALLOCATE(p);  -- Remove old data, prevent memory leak
  end procedure append;



begin

  process
    variable ptr      : int_vector_ptr_t;
    variable ptr_ptr  : int_vector_ptr_ptr_t;

    function to_string(iv : integer_vector) return string is
      variable l : std.textio.line;
    begin
      for i in iv'range loop
        std.textio.write(l, to_string(iv(i)) & " ");
      end loop;

      return l.all; -- I know this is memory leak, but its easy
    end function;

  begin
    for i in 0 to 10 loop
      append(ptr, i);
    end loop;

    for i in ptr.all'range loop
      report "ptr=" & to_string(ptr.all(i));
    end loop;


    ptr_ptr := new int_vector_ptr_t;

    for i in 0 to 10 loop
      --append(ptr_ptr.all, i);

      ptr := ptr_ptr.all;

      if i = 0 then
        ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'( (0 => i) );
      else
        ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'(ptr.all & i);
      end if;

      -- If you add these two lines, you get a NULL pointer, but why don't you get a null pointer
      -- reference above?

      report "ptr_data = " & to_string(ptr.all);
      --report "ptr_data = " & to_string(ptr.all(i));

      DEALLOCATE(ptr);  -- Remove old data, prevent memory leak

    end loop;

    for i in ptr_ptr.all.all'range loop
      report "ptr=" & to_string(ptr_ptr.all.all(i));
    end loop;

    wait;

  end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: It looks OK to me: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Ej_

Comment: any chance you can try with a newer version?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Matthew's example also analyzes, elaborates and simulates in ghdl.  An access value is a designator not a pointer. VHDL doesn't have pointers, it has access types (5.4) which provide access values (5.1) for allocated (not declared) objects (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.7 Allocators "In the absence of explicit deallocation, an implementation shall guarantee that any object created by the evaluation of an allocator remains allocated for as long as this object or one of its subelements is accessible directly or indirectly; that is, as long as it can be denoted by some name.").

Comment: @user1155120 example provided.

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the snippets that don't reproduce your problem ([which is algorithmic and not language implementation related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPSme.jpg)).

Comment: @user1155120 its now minimal and reproducable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process in architecture test of int_append_test can be modified to demonstrate the issue is algorithmic and not language implementation related:

```vhdl
architecture test of int_append_test is

  type int_vector_ptr_t is access integer_vector;
  type int_vector_ptr_ptr_t is access int_vector_ptr_t;

  procedure append (variable ptr: inout int_vector_ptr_t;
                    constant val: in    integer ) is
    variable p: int_vector_ptr_t;
    begin
        p := ptr;

        if ptr = null then
            ptr := new integer_vector'( (0 => val) );
        else
            ptr := new integer_vector'(p.all & val);
        end if;

        DEALLOCATE(p);  -- Remove old data, prevent memory leak
    end procedure append;

begin

    process
        variable ptr:       int_vector_ptr_t;
        variable ptr_ptr:   int_vector_ptr_ptr_t;

    function to_string(iv:  integer_vector) return string is
        variable l:  std.textio.line;
    begin
        for i in iv'range loop
          std.textio.write(l, to_string(iv(i)) & " ");
        end loop;

        return l.all;
    end function;

    begin
        for i in 0 to 10 loop
            append(ptr, i);
        end loop;

        for i in ptr.all'range loop
            report "ptr = " & to_string(ptr.all(i));
        end loop;

        ptr_ptr := new int_vector_ptr_t;

        for i in 0 to 10 loop

            ptr := ptr_ptr.all;

            if i = 0 then
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'( (0 => i) );
            else
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'(ptr.all & i);
            end if;

            if ptr = NULL then   -- test for NULL ptr ADDED
                report "ptr = NULL for i = " & integer'image(i); -- ADDED
            else
                report "ptr_data = " & to_string(ptr.all); -- MOVED HERE
            end if;

            DEALLOCATE(ptr);

        end loop;

        for i in ptr_ptr.all.all'range loop
            report "ptr = " & to_string(ptr_ptr.all.all(i));
        end loop;

        wait;

    end process;

end architecture;
```

The value of NULL is detected in the access value held by `ptr` and when run this gives:

```
ghdl -r --std=08 int_append_test
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 1
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 2
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 3
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 4
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 5
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 6
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 7
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 8
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 9
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 10
int_append_test.vhdl:62:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr = NULL for i = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
int_append_test.vhdl:64:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 1
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 2
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 3
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 4
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 5
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 6
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 7
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 8
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 9
int_append_test.vhdl:72:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 10
```

where the null value causing the error is reported instead of causing the error.

How is the value of `ptr` a `NULL`?

This can be seen across the start of the third loop statement:

```vhdl
        ptr_ptr := new int_vector_ptr_t;

        for i in 0 to 10 loop

            ptr := ptr_ptr.all;
```

Where `ptr_ptr` is an access value of access type `int_vector_ptr_ptr_t` which is itself an access type of type `int_vector_ptr_t.  We see that`ptr_ptr`is allocated but the value hasn't been initialized, it's a`NULL`value which is subsequently assigned to`ptr`.

The value doesn't become non `NULL` until the following if statement:

```vhdl
            if i = 0 then
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'( (0 => i) );
            else
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'(ptr.all & i);
            end if;
```

What happens here is the classical depending-on-a-value-before-it's-assigned, guaranteed to produce an error for a value of an access type.

If you move the assignment to `ptr` you'll also find the deallocate call is the wrong place, causing a NULL access on i = 1. Moving the deallocate call clears that up:

```vhdl
        for i in 0 to 10 loop

            -- ptr := ptr_ptr.all;  -- REMOVED

            if i = 0 then
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'( (0 => i) );
            else
                ptr_ptr.all := new integer_vector'(ptr.all & i);
            end if;

            ptr := ptr_ptr.all;  -- MOVED HERE

            -- if ptr = NULL then   -- test for NULL ptr ADDED
            --     report "ptr = NULL for i = " & integer'image(i); -- ADDED
            -- else
                report "ptr_data = " & to_string(ptr.all); -- MOVED HERE
            -- end if;

            -- DEALLOCATE(ptr);  -- REMOVED

        end loop;

        DEALLOCATE(ptr); -- MOVED HERE
```

The corrected code runs without error:

```
ghdl -r --std=08 int_append_test
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 1
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 2
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 3
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 4
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 5
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 6
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 7
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 8
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 9
int_append_test.vhdl:46:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 10
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
int_append_test.vhdl:66:17:@0ms:(report note): ptr_data = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 0
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 1
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 2
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 3
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 4
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 5
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 6
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 7
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 8
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 9
int_append_test.vhdl:76:13:@0ms:(report note): ptr = 10
```

Comment: Yes. In this case - my fault .. Thanks